# My tikzpicture won't work

Tags: tikz-trees

I'm pretty new to LaTex and I'm currently trying to draw an image using the tikzpicture package. However, everytime I go to compile my document, it won't work and it times out! Could you guys give me any pointers? This is my code (sorry if it's awful, as I said I'm new to this)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[] (a) at (0,0) {$G$};
  \node[] (b) at (2, 0) {$\G \times \overset{d}{\cdots} \times G$};
  \node[] (c) at (0, -2) {$\textrm{St}_G(1)$};
  \node[] (d) at (2, -2) {$\varphi(\textrm{St}_G(1))$};
  \node[] (e) at (0, -4) {$H$};
  \node[] (f) at (2, -4) {$\varphi(H)$};
  \node[] (g) at (0, -6) {$K$};
  \node[] (h) at (2, -6) {$\K \times \overset{d}{\cdots} \times K$};
  \node[] (i) at (0, -8) {$\cdots$};
  \node[] (j) at (2, -8) {$\cdots$};
  \path (a) edge node [left] {} (c);
  \path (b) edge node [left] {} (d);
  \path (c) edge node [left] {$\varphi$} (d);
  \path (c) edge node [left] {} (e);
  \path (d) edge node [left] {} (f);
  \path (e) edge node [left] {$\varphi$} (f);
  \path (e) edge node [left] {} (g);
  \path (f) edge node [left] {} (h);
  \path (g) edge node [left] {$\varphi$} (h);
  \path (g) edge node [left] {} (i);
  \path (h) edge node [left] {} (j);
  \path (i) edge node [left] {} (j);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: thank you for the edit!!! i was just trying to change it :)

Comment: I fixed your example so we could run it  but `\G`  and `\overset` undefined(possible amsmath for the latter?) Please edit to show your actual problem

Comment: also `! Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?.`   for this line `\node[] (h) at (2, -6) {$\K \times \overset{d}{\cdots} \times K$}`  don't ignore errors!!

Comment: Thank you :) my code is working now!

Answer (score 1):

Don't ignore Errors

TeX reports

```
! Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?
```

adding a `;` at the place indicated in the error message stops tex looping.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}
\newcommand\G{G}
\newcommand\K{K}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[] (a) at (0,0) {$G$};
  \node[] (b) at (2, 0) {$\G \times \overset{d}{\cdots} \times G$};
  \node[] (c) at (0, -2) {$\textrm{St}_G(1)$};
  \node[] (d) at (2, -2) {$\varphi(\textrm{St}_G(1))$};
  \node[] (e) at (0, -4) {$H$};
  \node[] (f) at (2, -4) {$\varphi(H)$};
  \node[] (g) at (0, -6) {$K$};
  \node[] (h) at (2, -6) {$\K \times \overset{d}{\cdots} \times K$};%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
  \node[] (i) at (0, -8) {$\cdots$};
  \node[] (j) at (2, -8) {$\cdots$};
  \path (a) edge node [left] {} (c);
  \path (b) edge node [left] {} (d);
  \path (c) edge node [left] {$\varphi$} (d);
  \path (c) edge node [left] {} (e);
  \path (d) edge node [left] {} (f);
  \path (e) edge node [left] {$\varphi$} (f);
  \path (e) edge node [left] {} (g);
  \path (f) edge node [left] {} (h);
  \path (g) edge node [left] {$\varphi$} (h);
  \path (g) edge node [left] {} (i);
  \path (h) edge node [left] {} (j);
  \path (i) edge node [left] {} (j);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```